# When running .lp files using clingo on MacOS, I got this error: <cmd>: error: file cannot be opened

Tags: clingo

For the same file, if I set the extension to .lp, it cannot be opened; however, changing the extension to .txt solves the problem. The function of running .lp files should be standard for Clingo, right? I also tried installing the package clingo-lp and clingo-lpx, none of them solved my problem yet.

I am wondering why, is it because the OS I use? Haven't tried it on Windows.

When I type in this:

```
% clingo /Users/lingxiaozhao/Documents/queens.lp -c n=8 0,
```

it should return all the stable models for the .lp file, but instead it returned:

```
clingo version 5.6.2
Reading from ...ingxiaozhao/Documents/queens.lp
<cmd>: error: file could not be opened:
  /Users/lingxiaozhao/Documents/queens.lp

*** ERROR: (clingo): parsing failed
UNKNOWN

Models       : 0+
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.001s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.001s
```

I tried installing the package clingo-lp and clingo-lpx, none of them solved the problem.

Comment: Weird. Are you sure your program doesn't contain syntax errors? May you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but a workaround:

```
cat /Users/lingxiaozhao/Documents/queens.lp | clingo -c n=8 0
```